# pylons blog frameworks

Tags: pylons

I'm looking to play around with pylons or pyramid but I don't want to start from scratch. I looked for a blog framework written in pylons or pyramid on the web but I can't find one. Does anyone know of one? Am I looking for the wrong thing maybe this isn't the best way to get started?

Comment: the bigger question is why you need a blog framework in pylons or pyramid in the first place

Comment: if you don't want to start from scratch why are you picking pylons/pyramid? Alas, there is at least one cms being developed that runs on top of pyramid. http://kotti.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @Jonathan Ong, I'm just looking to play around with Pylons or Pyramid. I've done the "hello world" example and I want to see how a proper project would be setup.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at http://code.adhocracy.de/en/ . Adhocracy runs on top of pylons...